# how to force browser to re-request page after history.back()

Tags: php, javascript, header

I've got two scripts: 1.php and 2.php. Here they are:

1.php

```
<?php

header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1; no-cache');
header('Expires: Tue, 1 May 1985 01:10:00 GMT');
header('ETag: "'.md5(rand(1, 1000)).'"');

print date('H:i:s');
?>
<a href="2.php">pay</a>
```

2.php

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">back</a>
```

Visitor lands on 1.php and then goes to 2.php. I want browser to re-request 1.php after vistor's click on "back" link. Currently, it doesn't work. How it can be managed?

upd. I can edit 1.php ONLY and cant edit 2.php.

Comment: please clarify what `On current state it doesn't work` mean. What happens if you click on back?

Comment: Why don't you skip the JavaScript and just use `href="1.php"`?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I can edit 1.php only. 1.php refers to my own website and 2.php refers to external system. If a vistor clicks on back link he returns to 1.php without refreshing this page. I can see it because the time showed on 1.php when visitor firstly comes to it is the same as when he returns to it from 2.php using "back" link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice you can't. Although browsers should send a new request for a non-cacheable page (ther are several things broken in the headers you are sending) both MSIE and Firefox will always use an in-memory copy within a certain timescale.

C.